# Android VideoView or SurfaceView to play videos?

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-videoview

which one should I use to weigh less in the device system and battery, the VideoView or the SurfaceView ?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you should ask whether to use SurfaceView or TextureView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`VideoView` uses a `SurfaceView`. In your areas of concern, they are equal.

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare. I´ve looking in google for a direct answer but not found any. Thank you again.

Comment: @pskink: Yeah, but that's complicated. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare i'm sorry, my comment was intended to OP, not you ;-)